# Receiving Bluetooth Files from Nexus 7

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, nexus-7

I have successfully paired and connected my Nexus 7 with my Ubuntu 12.04 PC.

I have successfully sent files from the PC to my Android device, but when I try to send files from Android to Ubuntu, the Nexus 7 reports

> request cannot be handled correctly

(I select file to transfer, then select: share via bluetooth, then select my Ubuntu PC)